# AzureAD SAML ACS URL accept HTTP endpoint for local development purposes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, acs

I would like to ask about how can I enter localhost endpoint in ACS URL for local development purposes.

As I read in Azure documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications#step-1-edit-the-basic-saml-configuration

> Or, for testing purposes you can specify multiple reply URLs (**local host** and public URLs) at one time.

My localhost is HTTP endpoint not HTTPS endpoint. On entering in Azure Portal, I got this error:

[image]

I’m wondering does ACS URL accept HTTP endpoint?
In the case of OpenID OIDC, I can enter HTTP localhost endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ACS URL accepts HTTP endpoint,your address is entered incorrectly, please enter the correct address, it is `http://localhost` instead of `http://localhostf`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my point is that on OpenID OIDC (your answer screenshot), enter `http://localhost` does work but on SAML enter `http://localhost` does not work

Comment: On the screenshot I input `http://localhostf` just to showup the validation messages